# JavaFX deploy extra File with Ant

Tags: java, javafx, deployment, ant

in my **JavaFX-Project** I imported an **.exe** file: **tool.exe**

Image [1](https://image.ibb.co/ekkprH/test1.png)

With the help of **Ant** I get the installation file:

Image [2](https://preview.ibb.co/ivKcdx/test2.png)

I install the application.
My goal is to include the **tool.exe** file in the installation folder:

Image [3](https://image.ibb.co/ex9okc/test3.png)

Can you please help me figure out which line of code I need to add to my Ant script?

```
<target name="init-fx-tasks">

    <path id="fxant">
        <filelist>
            <file name="${java.home}\..\lib\ant-javafx.jar" />
            <file name="${java.home}\lib\jfxrt.jar" />
        </filelist>
    </path>

    <taskdef resource="com/sun/javafx/tools/ant/antlib.xml" uri="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant" classpathref="fxant" />

</target>

<target name="setup-staging-area">

    <delete dir="externalLibs" />
    <delete dir="project" />
    <delete dir="projectRefs" />

    <mkdir dir="externalLibs" />
    <mkdir dir="project" />
    <mkdir dir="projectRefs" />

    <copy todir="project">
        <fileset dir="C:\Users\name\workspace\project\Test">
            <include name="src/**" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>

</target>

<target name='do-compile'>

    <delete dir="build" />

    <mkdir dir="build/src" />
    <mkdir dir="build/libs" />
    <mkdir dir="build/classes" />

    <copy todir="build/libs">
        <fileset dir="externalLibs">
        </fileset>
    </copy>

    <copy todir="build/src">
        <fileset dir="project/src">
            <include name="**/*" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>

    <javac includeantruntime="false" source="1.8" target="1.8" srcdir="build/src" destdir="build/classes" encoding="Cp1252">
        <classpath>
            <fileset dir="build/libs">
                <include name="*" />
            </fileset>
        </classpath>
    </javac>

    <copy todir="build/classes">
        <fileset dir="project/src">
            <exclude name="**/*.java" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>

</target>

<target name="do-deploy" depends="setup-staging-area, do-compile, init-fx-tasks">

    <delete file="dist" />
    <delete file="deploy" />

    <mkdir dir="dist" />
    <mkdir dir="dist/libs" />

    <copy todir="dist/libs">
        <fileset dir="externalLibs">
            <include name="*" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>

    <fx:resources id="appRes">
        <fx:fileset dir="dist" includes="Test.jar" />
        <fx:fileset dir="dist" includes="libs/*" />
        <fx:fileset dir="build" includes="tools/*" />
    </fx:resources>

    <fx:application id="fxApplication" name="TEST" mainClass="application.Main" toolkit="fx" />

    <mkdir dir="build/classes/META-INF" />

    <fx:jar destfile="dist/Test.jar">
        <fx:application refid="fxApplication" />
        <fileset dir="build/classes">
        </fileset>
        <fx:resources refid="appRes" />

        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Implementation-Vendor" value="Software" />
            <attribute name="Implementation-Title" value="TEST" />
            <attribute name="Implementation-Version" value="1" />
            <attribute name="JavaFX-Feature-Proxy" value="None" />
        </manifest>
    </fx:jar>

    <mkdir dir="deploy" />

    <fx:deploy embedJNLP="false" extension="false" includeDT="false" offlineAllowed="true" outdir="${basedir}/deploy" outfile="Test" nativeBundles="exe" updatemode="background">

        <fx:platform basedir="${java.home}" />
        <fx:info title="Test" vendor="Software" />
        <fx:application refId="fxApplication" />
        <fx:resources refid="appRes" />

    </fx:deploy>

</target>
```

I tried to add this line, but it did not work.

```
<copy todir="project">
    <fileset dir="C:\Users\name\workspace\project\Test">
        <include name="src/**" />
        <include name="tool.exe" />
    </fileset>
</copy>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it!

Maybe it can be useful to someone else.

You need to create the **resources** folder in the **dist** folder.

```
<mkdir dir="dist" />
<mkdir dir="dist/libs" />
...
<mkdir dir="dist/resources" /> <---------- This line
...
```

This folder is automatically copied.

I copied my file **tool.exe** inside.

```
<copy todir="dist/resources">
    <fileset dir="C:\Users\name\workspace\project\Test">
        <include name="tool.exe" />
    </fileset>
</copy>
```

and declared in **fx:resources**.

```
<fx:resources id="appRes">
    <fx:fileset dir="dist" includes="Test.jar" />
    <fx:fileset dir="dist" includes="libs/*" />
    ...
    <fx:fileset dir="dist" includes="resources/**" /> <---------- This line
    ...
</fx:resources>
```

Many thanks to everyone.

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to do this for hours.